# How to limit the number a loop does in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My code adds the sum if each 'purchase' on a new line, but I only want them to be able to do 5 entries. copy and paste this code into visual studio as a console application then debug or run it or whatever. I'm new to C#, and would like to know how to only allow 5 numbers. I'm trying not to deviate too far from my code below. That being said, There may be a more advanced way to do this, but I do not want that.

```
namespace SumFiveDoubles
{
    class TotalPurchase
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            double purchase;
            double total = 0;
            string inputString;
            const double QUIT = 0;
            Console.Write("Enter a purchase amount >> ");
            inputString = Console.ReadLine();
            purchase = Convert.ToDouble(inputString);
            while (purchase != QUIT)
            {
                total += purchase;
                Console.Write("Enter another purchase amount or " + QUIT + " to calculate >> "); //I only want this to appear 4 more times\\
                inputString = Console.ReadLine();
                purchase = Convert.ToDouble(inputString);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Your total is {0}", total.ToString("C"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use a for loop I guess?...LOL so many Answers I should have post it as an answer...

Comment: replace `while (purchase != QUIT)` with while `for(int i<5 ;purchase != QUIT && i<5 ;i++)` and see if is what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int count = 0;
while (purchase != QUIT && ++count < 5)
```

Comment: @user3351955, you should mark it as the answer if it was the solution.

Comment: i did, it just said i needed to wait 5 minutes, then i had to get off, thanks though

Answer (score 1):

The expression inside parentheses of the `while` loop is its continuation condition. If you do not want the loop to go past a certain number of iterations, make an iteration counter, and make a composite condition that turns `false` once the counter exceeds a certain number, or the `purchase` becomes `QUIT`, whatever happens first.

```
int count = 0;
while (purchase != QUIT && count < 5) {
    ... // Do your stuff
    count++;
}
```

You could also use a `for` loop put the declaration and the increment of the counter in one spot:

```
for (int count = 0 ; purchase != QUIT && count < 5 ; count++) {
    ... // Do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a counter to you're while..

```
        int max = 0;
        while (purchase != QUIT && max < 5)
        {
            total += purchase;
            Console.Write("Enter another purchase amount or " + QUIT + " to calculate >> "); //I only want this to appear 4 more times\\
            inputString = Console.ReadLine();
            purchase = Convert.ToDouble(inputString);
            max++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Your total is {0}", total.ToString("C"));
```

So your loop will either exit when purchase == QUIT or the max is reached.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`for`-loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx):

```
double purchase;
double total = 0;
string inputString;
const double QUIT = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Enter a purchase amount >> ");
    inputString = Console.ReadLine();
    purchase = Convert.ToDouble(inputString);
    if(purchase == QUIT)
        break;

    total += purchase;
    Console.Write("Enter another purchase amount or " + QUIT + " to calculate >> "); //I only want this to appear 4 more times\\
    inputString = Console.ReadLine();
    purchase = Convert.ToDouble(inputString);
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the `while` loop to be the one running only 5 times